# Convert VBA bitwise operator to C#

Tags: c#, vba, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a bitwise operations in VBA and now I want to convert that to C#.

I tried converting using the C# bitwise operators but I didn't get the result.

VBA Bitwise Operations

```vb
Bit1 = (Var1 And 2 ^ 14) Or (Var1 And 2 ^ 15)
```

C# Bitwise Operations

```
var Bit1 = (bitvalue >> 14) | (bitvalue >> 15);
```

Since VBA doesn't have bit shift operators we use 2^places for right shift and in C# we can simply use >> for right shift operator, but it's not giving me the result which I am getting it in VBA. What could be the reason?

This is my full C# function and it's similar in VBA:

```
public void bitcalc()
{


    var Bit1 = (bitvalue >> 14) | (bitvalue >> 15);
    if (Bit1 == 16384) getISO15031BitsLetter = "C";

    else if (Bit1 == 32768) getISO15031BitsLetter = "B";


    else if (Bit1 == 49152) getISO15031BitsLetter = "U";


    else getISO15031BitsLetter = "P" ;


}
```

Comment: Um, that ain't VB.NET.  That appears to be C#.

Comment: _"now i want to convert that to Vb.net--C#"_ - VB.NET and C# are not the same thing in case you think otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Vb.net and C# are not same.... :) quick googling pointed that C# is a flavor of .Net..... so C# is based on .NET framework

Comment: Both VB.NET and C# are based on the .NET Framework (hence the **".NET"**-part in **VB.NET**), however their syntax and language structures are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code does not shift the input. It only masks it. A direct translation could be:

```cs
var Bit1 = (Var1 & (1 << 14)) | (Var1 & (1 << 15));
```

There are multiple variations to this. E.g., you could mask both bits at the same time:

```cs
var Bit1 = (Var1 & (3 << 14)); // decimal 3 is binary 11
```

Comment: Thank you ... both the variations worked. before posting i had tried with 1 <<14 and 1 << 15 but i had parenthesis for var1 also... .